# Can't find mysql data in install directory

Tags: windows-7, mysql

I was looking for my mysql data on my harddrive, so i went to the install directory (C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data) but there are only a few of the databases displayed I actually use. Hidden folders are enabled so far...
Is there any other directory I should check?

I know I could look for the `my.ini`, but I can't find it in the install directory.
There is just a `my-default.ini`, which should be a template for generating the `my.ini` file at installation it says.
I'm running Windows 7 x64...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\`

Sample `.ini` files are placed there in older installations of MySQL 5.

All the .exe files in `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin` expects my.ini to exist in `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\`. In other words, the full path for my.ini should be `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`. If it does not exist, you can create the `my.ini` there. [I mentioned this location in StackOverflow over a Year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/mysql-my-ini-location/14598246#14598246).

As for the location of the data, you can get that info by running

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

If that command does not say `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data`, then the output given says where mysqld sees the data folder.

If you are interested in changing it.

You should first run

```
C:\> net stop mysql
```

Then create or change `C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini` with all the options you want, such as `datadir`.

Then, start mysql with

```
C:\> net start mysql
```

CAVEAT: You can only run `net stop mysql` and `net start mysql` from the command line when you open the DOS Command Line as Administrator.